# how to return my forked repo to the original repo

Tags: git, github, fork, commit

I did 'fetch and merge' to incorporate all the commits done to the original repo that my forked repo was behind.

However,my forked repo is now 3 commits ahead of the original repo.

I want to simply remove those commits. So the end result is as if I am just forking the original repo for the first time.

I have not been able to figure out how to do that. I've only been able to find on the Internet how to update the original repo by starting a pull request.

Also, is there an easy way to view the actual commits that are the differences between the forked and the original repos?

[image]

Comment: You can use [`git-reset`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-reset):  `git reset --hard <commit>`

Comment: @joshmeranda I was hoping theres an option to just get rid of all differences by which my forked repo is ahead.

Comment: thats what git reset will do. It will "reset" the branch to a previous state (before you merged your fork). Without the `--hard` flag it will keep the changes for you to review before  dropping, but with the flag it will drop them automatically.]\

Answer (score 0):

You can do
`git reset --hard upstream/master`.
It will reset your master's HEAD to how upstream master's HEAD looks.

Mind you if there was any work you did that is in the 3 ahead commits, it will be lost.